# jsdom document.createWindow() returns empty for non-empty document

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I'm trying to follow the very short, simple setup instructions at https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom under section "**Creating a browser-like BOM/DOM/Window**".  Unfortunately, after the 3rd line (the .createWindow step), I do console.log(window) and it prints an empty object.  There should be at least window.document there, but there isn't.  It seems as though document.createWindow is acting the same as jsdom.createWindow.

Here's my code so far:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;

document = jsdom("<html><head></head><body>hello world</body></html>");
window = document.createWindow();

console.log(window); // output: {}

console.log(window.document.innerHTML); // error, cannot read innerHTML on undefined
```

So, what stupid thing am I doing wrong?

FYI document is created correctly.  Printing it outputs a very large object.

I am using a Mac.

Comment: this works for me and not sure why are you getting those errors.

Comment: Node.js version and jsdom version?

Answer (score 4):

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;
document = jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body>hello jsdom</body></html>');
window = document.createWindow();
console.log(window);
var txt = window.document.body.innerHTML;
console.log(txt);
```

Comment: var txt = window.document.body.innerHTML;

Answer (score 2):

Problem was due to an installation error with Contextify.  I'm used to developing on either Windows or *NIX and on Mac, due to *NIX terminal, assumed I would have things like Make.  Problem was solved by installing Xcode with command line tools, which installs Make among other things, which solved installation error for Contexify, which resolved the overall issue.

Comment: Yep, I had this same issue and that was the problem for me: I did `npm install` on my mac, checked it in, and when things ran on our linux CI box, they completely choked. Now we just automatically run `npm install jsdom` before running the tests and it gets the right contextify for the current environment.